# IRE Rule On ServiceNow CMDB

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I have created an Identification rule on IP Network CMDB table in ServiceNow -
[IRE Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aYjw.png) and this works perfectly fine to tackle with duplicate records when using Transform map on import set to dump data into the CMDB table.

However, the same IRE doesn't work when I try posting record via ServiceNow REST API directly to the CMDB table, when posting the same record twice it accepts it without any error.

I thought IRE rules once set are applied on CMDB tables and works for every transactions on them, but it doesn't seem to the case.

Can someone please help me understand, why IRE rules are not working when using REST API to post records directly to CMDB table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem - we simply have to use the REST API for IRE from servicenow looks like this: https://<host_name>.service-now.com/api/now/identifyreconcile?sysparm_data_source=ImportSet

Answer (score 0):

There is a special API to honour the IRE

https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/paris/rest/c_IdentifyReconcileAPI